# FontAwesome icons inside anchors not animating on chrome

Tags: html, css, css-animations, font-awesome

I'm trying to animate a fontawesome icon, inside a span it works fine, but when I put the icon inside an anchor it stops working on chrome, on IE it works.

I am using FontAwesome 3.2.1
and this is my code

Html:

```
<a>
    <i class="icon-wrench rotator"></i> 
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.rotator {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 2.5s 4 ease;
    -webkit-transform-origin:90% 35%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
    }

    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(112deg);
    }
}
```

I tried it with FontAwesome 3.0.2 and it works, when I upgraded to 3.2.1 it stopped working, on chrome at least.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**
I also have more html inside the anchor and I don't want that to rotate so adding the 'rotator' class to the anchor won't do it

**Edit**
This is the actual html (the example above is simplified):

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="icon-bell-alt icon-animated-bell icon-only"></i>
    <span class="badge badge-success">5</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the rotator class to the anchor instead.  It will start rotating on page load, assuming this is what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/7kANu/4/

```
<a class="rotator">
    <i class="icon-wrench"></i> 
</a>
```

EDIT:  Are you not able to wrap the icon in a div and assign the rotator class to that as a workaround?

Comment: The problem is that I have more html inside the anchor and I don't want it to rotate, I'll edit my question, thanks

Comment: Can you post an example with the additional HTML?